# Java Standard System Input and Buffered Reader

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

After trying to test this Bufferered Reader

```
import java.io.*;


public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader Br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    if (Br.readLine() == "one") print1();
    if (Br.readLine() == "two") print2();
}
public static void print1(){
    System.out.print("1");
}   
public static void print2(){
    System.out.print("2");
}
}
```

Nothing I can type in will get it to print. If I change the first "if" statement to

```
if (Br.readLine().startsWith("one") print1();
```

it will print "1" if I type in "one". Why does this happen?

Comment: Don't compare strings with `==`. Use `.equals()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

when you are comparing strings you should change up `==` to be `.equals()` due to the fact that `.equals()` compares the contents of the strings to each other or is used to compare objects. `==` checks for reference equality or is used to compare primitives. I changed your code below:

```
if (Br.readLine().equals("one")) print1();
if (Br.readLine().equals("two")) print2();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Br.readLine() == "one") print1();
if (Br.readLine() == "two") print2();
```

**==** is comparing references of two string which is not same because consider both as different String Objects.

In java String Variable implicitly converted to String object as your comparison **"one"** is now object stored at some location other that location of String retrived from `Br.readLine()` So in short both referencec are not Equal.

While `equals()`  method compares String Object Values in this kind of case.

```
if (Br.readLine().equals("one")) print1();
if (Br.readLine().equals("two")) print2();
```

While in int (Primitive types) **==** works fine here AutoBoxing and UnBoxing takes place.

```
    Integer i=new Integer(5); 
    if(i==5){System.out.println("SAME");}
```